# Cannot load swf file to browser with flash player 11

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-7, flash

I have recently installed FP 11.However I contsanly get message to install FP 11 when oppening one of my swf files emebeded in a html page.

It is ridiculous, I installed FP 11 and still get message to install it :) :(

What could be the problem? I am on Win7

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? I probably would not call this an AS3 question, nor a programming question. Try re-installing FP.

Comment: It seems that swfobject doesnt work its job well. So maybe I guess it is not updated or has issue with FP 11. I created new html page and added "object" tag to embed the swf and it worked. Weird :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I got to an answer. You must change the swfobject.js in your project to the newest version but also expressInstall.swf